# Check whether 3 strings are located in a same sentence or not -Java

Tags: java

I am checking whether 3 strings located in a same sentence or not.

For example the sentence  **Barack born on November 4 1960.**
In this sentence string1 is Barack Obama
                string2 is born on
                string3 is November 4 1960

MY idea is to check if there is no period(".") in between string1, string2, and string3, I can believe that 3 strings located in a same sentence.

But sometimes the sentence is like **Mr.smith and mrs.smith both born on April 2 1970.**

If i just check for period(".") my approach fails. Can someone suggest me is there any other way to check for 3 strings located in a same sentence or not?

Comment: What's 'fullstop'? But regardless, why don't you check a) is string 1 there? b) is string2? c) is string3? if all 3 are `true`, then all 3 are there...

Comment: @iluxa 'fullstop' is what they teach in school as the end of a sentence '.'

Comment: oh I see. @user12345, what do you do to check for string1 being in the sentence right now?

Comment: These are two completely different things. First, splitting a string into sentences, second, test, whether one, two, or three strings are contained in a substring returned by the first step. The latter is trivial. The former can be hard, if it should not work with English only. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html

Comment: If those 3 strings are located in the same sentence i can believe that the particular person is born on particular date

Comment: That was not the question. iluxa asked you what you have *tried* so far. Your code, your know?

Comment: I have start and end indexes of all 3 strings through UIMA framework.So i am reading the file which contains the above sentence and read the characters between strings and check for "."

Comment: I don't think you can determine sentence boundaries without grammar parsing (super hard). Because You can get Mr. Smith and there is no way to know if this is a sentence delimiter or not, really. Maybe you could add a blacklist of words the sentence can end with, therefore this would be eliminated, but it's unreliable.

Comment: @MightyPork: BreakIterator *does* these things for you…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, use `BreakIterator`. It does the right thing for you.

```
BreakIterator i=BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
final String text = "Mr. smith and mrs.smith both born on April 2 1970. Barack born on November 4 1960.";
i.setText(text);
for(int s=i.first(), e=i.next(); e>=0; s=e, e=i.next())
{
  System.out.println("Sentence: from "+s+" to "+e+" \""+text.substring(s, e)+'"');
}
```

Once you know the boundaries of the sentences, you should know how to match the found string locations with it.

Comment: nice one, never heard of this class before, but it seems awesome !

Comment: hi, The BreakIterator is splitting the text onto valid sentences with boundaries where each boundary ranging form 0 to n...But my strings has start and end indexes in bytes.All the string indexes in file ranging from 0 to 30k or 4ok(depends on the file size) byte size. How do i check these 3 strings with start and end index are locate din a same valid sentence(which have boundaries)

Comment: I don’t know neither, how you got these indices in the bytes of the file nor how you received the `String` out of this file contents. But don’t put these details here as it’d blow up the comments. Open a new question. Matching the byte and char indices depends on the encoding used for the process of creating the `String` out of the file’s bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] toCheck = new String[] { ... };
String sentence = ".....";
Boolean allFound = true;
for (String s : toCheck) {
    if (sentence.indexOf(s) == -1) {
        allFound = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works fine for checking whether the sentence contains 3 strings or not.But my question is different.I have 3 strings with start and end indexes.Then i go and read a file where 3 strings located, then check these 3 strings located in a same sentence or not

Comment: Any reason for using `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?